# What could cause Chrome to open a new window form window.open() and display the source and not the rendered page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As the title states what could cause Chrome to display the source of a page instead of the rendered page when opening a new window with window.open().

What could be causing this? A security issue, bug? If so what are some other approaches to use window.open() or something similar or a modern way of doing this?

Note, it works correctly in Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: No way to know without more details. Does it render fine without window.open???

Comment: Bad mime type maybe

Comment: Check the response headers in the network tab for the content-type https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the reponse header and that seems to be providing clues of what might be happening.